# Swift 3.0 How to Change a Button Title Using TableView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

I have a table view with subclassed table view cells. I have attached a button and hooked this up to the table view cell's VC. I want the button to say 'Add' upon loading, 'Subtract' when clicked and back to 'Add' when clicked again. But I am having trouble understanding how I can relate the row number with the state of the button.

**VC with table view:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TVCell
    cell.cellDelegate = self

    if (searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func didPressButton(cell: TVCell) {

    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
                   return
    }

    print("Button tapped on row \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

**VC for table view cell:**

```
protocol TVCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressButton(cell: TVCell)
}

class TVCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    weak var cellDelegate: TVCellDelegate?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.cellDelegate = nil
    }

    // connect the button from your cell with this method
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        self.cellDelegate?.didPressButton(cell: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Please format your code, this looks messy with all those random empty lines.

Comment: How am I able to set the title of the button and change it?

Comment: @Kevin you can configure your states of the button and add the titles appropriately

`button.setTitle("Add",for: .normal)
button.setTitle("Subtract",for: .selected)`


When the button is tapped you can say 

`if(button.isSelected){
button.isSelected = false
}else{
button.isSelected = true
}`

This will be when button is pressed. its more of a pseudo code

Comment: Ok, do I put this in my cellForRowAt delegate?

Comment: you should use button method selected to make it more easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the buttons' state in your view controller and change the text after reusing and button pressing.

**VC with TableView:**

```
var isSubtracting = [IndexPath: Bool]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TVCell
    cell.cellDelegate = self

    if isSubtracting[indexPath] ?? false {
         cell.addButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
    } else {
         cell.addButton.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)
    }

    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    if(searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func didPressButton(indexPath: IndexPath) {
   guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TVCell else {
        return
    }

   if isSubtracting[indexPath] ?? false {
         isSubtracting[indexPath] = false
         cell.addButton.setTitle("Subtract", for: .normal)
    } else {
         isSubtracting[indexPath] = true
         cell.addButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

**VC for table view cell:**

```
protocol TVCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressButton(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class TVCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    weak var cellDelegate: TVCellDelegate?

    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.cellDelegate = nil
    }

    // connect the button from your cell with this method
        @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        self.cellDelegate?.didPressButton(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to set the title of button and be able to change it using this format. How am I able to do this?

Comment: In didPressButton function, it does not recognize cell.addButton. I don't think the cell in the function is referring to the same cell in cellForRowAt

Comment: it still doesn't recognize it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: My bad. Fixed again.

Comment: Great, just one last thing, the button only shows up when the cell is initially clicked. How can I get it such that the button is visible immediately?

Comment: cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.addButton) did the trick!

Comment: How to do it if I use sections instead of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the title's for the states of buttons like this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TVCell
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        cell.indexPath = indexPath

        cell.addButton.setTitle("Add",for: .normal)
        cell.addButton.setTitle("Subtract",for: .selected)

        if(searchActive) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
```

and tableViewCell

```
protocol TVCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressButton(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class TVCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    weak var cellDelegate: TVCellDelegate?

    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.cellDelegate = nil
    }

    // connect the button from your cell with this method
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if(sender.isSelected){
            sender.isSelected = false
        }else{
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
        self.cellDelegate?.didPressButton(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```